# Elasticsearch - configuration, filter plugin, spliting one field into two

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, config, logstash

I am working with logs from a Zscaler proxy. One of the field is composed of the url and the port's number:

```
URL_PORT: www.google.fr:443
```

I just simply want to split this field into two.

```
URL: www.google.fr

PORT: 443
```

I've tried

```
mutate{ 
   split {
      "terminator" => ":",
      "add_field" => "URL",
      "add_field" => "PORT"
   }
}
```

but nothing happened...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use another `grok` instead:

```
grok {
  match => [ "URL_PORT", "%{IPORHOST:URL}:%{WORD:PORT}" ]
  #remove_field => [ "URL_PORT" ]
}
```

or use it along with main `grok` filter